# Turn iPhone into Dumb USB Drive

Tags: iphone, usb

I am looking to turn my iPhone into a standard USB drive that will work with any device that accepts USB (for instance plugging into a TV). I do not mind completely killing the iOS firmware on it (I would in fact prefer that) but I can not do anything on the device itself since the screen and power button are broken (my reason for wanting to do this in the first place).

Thanks :)

Comment: Your best bet will be to enable Disk access in iTunes. I doubt that it will mount on a tv though. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1478?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: What model iPhone are we talking about here? Get the exact model and I'll try to lend you a hand.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I don't Apple's tutorial about using the device as a storage drive will work in this case. This only used to work for older iPod Classic devices as far as I know. There exist apps in the App Store (both free and paid or with paid upgrade) that could bring the iPhone as close as possible to a regular USB drive. Check this resource: [Turn your iPhone into a USB flash drive](http://www.copytrans.net/blog/turn-your-iphone-into-a-usb-flash-drive/)